# How to read from a text file and adding to array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, filereader

How would I go about reading numbers from a text file and adding them to an array?

**textfile**: HEAPinput2.txt

```
12
9
10
11
12
2
4
6
5
3
1
7
8
```

What I have here is a snippet of my code. If needed I will provide my whole main. But essentially I have a switch statement, when user chooses **R** read from a file and sort them into the array. I've been looking online and have been seeing different ways of doing it, I have done it as shown below, but have been running into some errors

```
case 'R':
file.open("<path of HEAPinput>");
if(!file){
        cout<<"There was a problem opening file HEAPinput2.txt for reading";
        exit(0);
 }
else{
        int count = 0;
        std:: int count;
        while(file>>count){
                    count++; //making sure it increments the
        }
        elme = *new ELEMENT[count];
        cout<<count; //prints out 8 for some reason
    }
    break;
```

Comment: I think you're walking on yourself. Try making `int count` and `std:: int count` different names. That will ensure the variable you actually want is used. If you still have a problem after that, feel free to ask.

Comment: What are "some errors" ? Please include a [mcve] and the error message

Comment: Do yourself a favour and use a `std::vector`. This code would be literally three lines and no bugs. Arrays are primitive, under-powered, verbose and above all difficult.

Comment: also, `cout<<count` probably outputs 8 since cout is actually std::cout, meaning it uses std::count, which is filled from file>>count because file is probably an std::ifstream. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: `*new ELEMENT[count]` discards the address of the allocated memory. It’s a memory leak.

Comment: @PeteBecker given you can't see the scope of the variable; how can you be sure (though I'm not saying it doesn't leak - or is exception safe)?

Comment: @UKMonkey — you’re right: if the type of `elme` is `ELEMENT &` the code can use `delete &elme` to release the memory. Of course, that’s a horrible thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

To sum up what others have said, this is extremely easy with `std::vector`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
    std::ifstream file;
    file.open ("<path of HEAPinput>");
    if(!file)
    {
        std::cout << "There was a problem opening file HEAPinput2.txt for reading";
        exit (0);
    }

    std::vector <int> v;
    int i;
    while (file >> i)
        v.push_back (i);
    file.close ();
}
```

More details on `std::vector` here:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Comment: And you can even get rid of the manual loop if you use `std::copy()` with `std::istream_iterator` and `std::back_inserter`, eg: `std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(file), std::istream_iterator(), std::back_inserter(v));`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Don't need the copy. The vector can be created by passing two iterators. `std::vector<int>  v(std::istream_iterator<int>{file}, std::istream_iterator<int>{})`

Comment: @MartinYork sure, if you fill the `vector` during its initialization.  But, if not, then `std::copy()` comes in handy for this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the first integer of the text file is the number of remaining integers to be read, and that `elme` is an `int*`, and that you are not allowed for this exercise to use vectors:

```
else{
    int count = 0;    // this should REALLY be declared in same block as elme
    int i=0; 
    if(file>>count) {  
        elme = new int[count];   // assuming that count is valid and not 0
        while (i<count && file>>elme[i]) 
            i++;   
        count = i; //  to adjust the number of items to the number really read
    }
    cout<<count; 
}
break;
```

If you're allowed to use vectors,  then go to Paul Sander's answer because vector is really century XXI for C++, whereas dynamically allocated arrays are something like the medieval age.